# How are watchers and filters treated within the AngularJS digest loop?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-filter

I understand that both scope watchers and filters are executed repetitively within the digest loop. However the following is a bit unclear to me:

- Are they executed the same amount of cycles?
- Are both triggered by the same circumstances?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Watches are checked every digest cycle.  And a `$watch` can watch an [Angular expression](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression).  Inside an expression there can be a [filter](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter) which Angular must evaluate (using [`$interpolate`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24interpolate)) to decide if the watched expression has changed.

**Are both triggered by the same circumstances?**

So, filters aren't run directly by `$digest` but are rather run as a consequence of a `$watch`.  In effect, filters are triggered by the evaluation of watched expressions.

There's a few reasons filters get talked about specially with regard to the performance of `$digest`.  Looking at these two expressions:

Expression 1: `{{searchText+2}}`

Expression 2: `{{searchText | myFilter:true}}`

Both expressions will be evaluated everytime a `$digest` is triggered.  So one risk area is simply that `myFilter` could be complex and end up using a lot more processor cycles than something simple (like the above +2).

A bit less obviously, a filter can cause extra runs of all watchers if it's not idempotent.  On each run of `$digest` a dirty bit is set if any of the watches results in a change.  And it reruns all the watches again if that dirty bit is set.  This allows any changes to be propagated.  For instance if `searchText` is changed by one of the watches then Angular needs to give all the other watchers a chance to see if their results depend on `searchText` and thus should change.

Herein lies the difference between expressions 1 and 2 above.  As a worst case scenario imagine `myFilter` returns a random number.  `$digest` runs, sees a change  when evaluating the watches (the previous result of the filter doesn't match the new result) so it runs through the watch list again.  Because the filter returns a random number it's results have very likely changed, triggering yet another run of `$digest`. etc, etc... Angular has a built in stop after 10 loops through it's watch list- it figures if the results don't stabilize after 10 tries then something is wrong and so it gives up throwing "Error: 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!"

**Are they executed the same amount of cycles?**

Therefore **at a minimum each watched expression (including any filters) is run twice per `$digest`**.  Once because of the change that triggered `$digest` and once more to check if that result needs to propagate.  If that propagation resulted in any changes then the watches and filters will be run again until nothing changes.

And, of course, if multiple watched expressions use the same filter then that filter will be run, following the above, for each expression.

Comment: Awesome explanation, thanks. Sorry, I got your answer shortly after my question, but then I just simply forgot to accept it!